# Giving access to global variables in __main__ to pytest session

Tags: python, pytest

I'm curious if something along these lines is possible where a module global can be initialized in `__main__` and yet made accessible to pytest when it runs using its `pytest.main()` mechanism.

My initial attempt seems to indicate in the negative about passing global state into the pytest session...

```
import pytest

globalList = []


def test_globalList() :
    global globalList
    print( "globalList: {}".format( globalList))
    assert globalList


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Main Start')
    globalList.append(1)
    globalList.append(2)
    globalList.append(3)

    pytest_options = [ __file__ ]
    print( "globalList: {}".format( globalList))
    print('\n\n\n\n')
    pytest.main( pytest_options  ) # run pytest for just this file
    print('Main Complete')
```

I yield the following console output

```
Main Start
globalList: [1, 2, 3]


=================================== test session starts ================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.10, pytest-4.0.2, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
rootdir: /Users/USER/, inifile:
collected 1 item

test_temp.py F                                                    [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===========================
___________________________________ test_globalList ____________________

    def test_globalList() :
        print( "globalList: {}".format( globalList))
>       assert globalList
E       assert []

test_temp.py:39: AssertionError
----------------------------------- Captured stdout call ---------------
globalList: []
=================================== 1 failed in 0.09 seconds ===========
Main Complete
```

What concept in pytest am I failing to understand that would alert me in advance that such an attempt is not possible. Is there a way to share global state in the `pytest.main` invocation?

---

## UPDATE

turns out the globalList is an entirely new instance, yet the process and threads are the same in both cases. A module load is occurring under the pytest context that is completely separate from the **main** context. Quoting a note from the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=pytest.main()#calling-pytest-from-python-code)

> ### Note
>
> Calling pytest.main() will result in importing your tests and any modules that they import.

```
import pytest
import os
import threading

globalList = []

print( "\n__name__ : {}".format( __name__ ))
print("process ID : {}".format(hex(os.getpid())))
cur_thread = threading.current_thread()
print( "thread ID : {}".format( hex(id(cur_thread )) ))
print( "thread Name : {}".format( cur_thread.name ))
print( "globalList ID : {}".format(hex(id(globalList))))

def test_globalList() :
    global globalList
    print( "globalList: {}".format( globalList)) # TODO this will be empty in the pytest session, somehow this approach fails to bring this variable into scope.
    assert globalList

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Main Start')
    globalList.append(1)
    globalList.append(2)
    globalList.append(3)

    pytest_options = [ __file__ , '-s']
    print( "globalList: {}".format( globalList))
    print('\n\n\n\n')
    pytest.main( pytest_options  ) # run pytest for just this file
    print('Main Complete')
```

And the corresponding console output...

```
__name__ : __main__
process ID : 0xa43e
thread ID : 0x10ac9b190
thread Name : MainThread
globalList ID : 0x10b476320
Main Start
globalList: [1, 2, 3]




=================================== test session starts ================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.10, pytest-4.0.2, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
rootdir: /Users/USER, inifile:
plugins: lazy-fixture-0.5.1, html-1.20.0, metadata-1.8.0
collecting ...
__name__ : test_temp
process ID : 0xa43e
thread ID : 0x10ac9b190
thread Name : MainThread
globalList ID : 0x10bb46128
collected 1 item

test_temp.py globalList: []
F

=================================== FAILURES ===========================
___________________________________ test_globalList ____________________

    def test_globalList() :
        global globalList
        print( "globalList: {}".format( globalList))
>       assert globalList
E       assert []

test_temp.py:50: AssertionError
=================================== 1 failed in 0.10 seconds ===========
Main Complete
```

And right away some differences pop out, the module name and address to the list are different...

```
__name__      : __main__      test_temp   <--different
process ID    : 0xa43e        0xa43e
thread ID     : 0x10ac9b190   0x10ac9b190
thread Name   : MainThread    MainThread
globalList ID : 0x10b476320   0x10bb46128 <--different
```

Comment: Pytest imports the module a second time, which executes `globalList = []` a second time and at that point the `__name__ != '__main__'`, so the list doesn't get populated. Have you tried to use a session fixture to achieve something similar ?

Comment: You can try to insert a print statement at the module level after the list definition, you should see it twice. But you will need to add `"-s"` to your arguments: `pytest_options = [__file__, "-s"]`. Otherwise pytest will capture the output.

Comment: Aha, a separate import, I see the significance of the Note under [Calling pytest from Python code](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=pytest.main()#calling-pytest-from-python-code) more clearly now. _Note
Calling `pytest.main()` will result in importing your tests and any modules that they import._

Comment: I was experimenting with an idea to push some global state that's dynamically generated in some hardware tests that would be fixed/static by the time I kicked off the pytest invocation. This was in the hopes to work around issues [Using fixtures in pytest.mark.parametrize #349](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349) and [Possible to expand the fixture return value in parametrize? #9](https://github.com/TvoroG/pytest-lazy-fixture/issues/9) since all the parametrization happens at collection time and as far as I can tell imposes some static constraints on the data's existence.